# Validation to upload jpg files only in nodejs using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm using multer to upload files in nodejs. Below is my code.

```
var multer = require('multer');
var imagefolder = __base + 'public/complaintimages';

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        if (common.ImageMimeTypes.indexOf(file.mimetype) < 0) {
            common.ActionOutput.Status = common.ActionStatus.Error;
            common.ActionOutput.Message = 'Invalid image file: ' + file.originalname;
            cb(new Error(JSON.stringify(common.ActionOutput)), null);
        } else
            cb(null, imagefolder);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var filenm = randomstring.generate(10);
        console.log(filenm + file.originalname);
        cb(null, filenm + file.originalname);
    },
    onError: function (err, next) {
        console.log('error', err);
        next(err);
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

I only allowed jpg files to upload by putting the mime type check which is working fine.
But when i upload any other type of file, control does not go into onError block so that i can return a proper validation message to the user like '`please upload valid jpg files.`'
Please advise.

Comment: see the mimetype in multer

Comment: check console.log(file.mimetype); it will return image/jpeg

Comment: you can try this code:

        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            console.log(file.mimetype);
        }

Comment: I already written a code to check mimetype which is working fine. my concern is to return a proper message to user if file is not of jpg type. @VinayPandya

Comment: new Error('Invalid image file: ' + file.originalname;)

Comment: after this control won't going to my desire place, it's going express error handler which i do not want to go. I only want to return a message to user from here only. @VinayPandya

Comment: cb('Invalid image file: '+file.originalname, null);

Answer (score 1):

A different approach for the upload validation, use the `fileFilter` callback https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter.

It is actually quite complicated to decide what is the file actual type, so instead of using mime type use the (Detect the file type of a Buffer/Uint8Array) https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type. It's a better approach then deciding based on the mime type, but does not guarantee that it has been faked.

Comment: The buffer is not available if you use diskStorage. Or is it?